# Enviar conteúdo de inputs para banco de dados

Tags: php, html5, banco-de-dados, front-end, back-end

Estou tendo um problema ao tentar fazer com que os valores destes inputs sejam enviados para um banco de dados, meu conhecimento de php é bem basico, tentei pesquisar em varios forums para ver se achava algo mas não tive sucesso.
Eu gostaria de ajuda para fazer isso.

```
<div id="data">
    <section>

        <label for="">Nome:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="nome" required>
        <br>
        <label for="">Sobrenome:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="sobrenome" required>
        <br>
        <label for="">Cargo:</label>
        <br>
        <select id="cargo">
            <option value="desenvolvedorFront">Desenvolvedor - Front-End</option>
            <option value="desenvolvedorBack">Desenvolvedor - Back-End</option>
            <option value="designerGrafico">Designer Gráfico</option>
            <option value="auditor">Auditor</option>
            <option value="analistaFinanceiro">Analísta Financeiro</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <button id="confirmar" onclick="confirmaInputData()">Confirmar</button>
        <div id="outputData"></div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu código não está muito organizado na parte do HTML. Não dá pra ter uma noção exata do seu problema. Pelo que você relatou, essa sua função JavaScript não é necessária. Só se você talvez quisesse usar AJAX, mas mesmo assim não vejo muito fundamento nessa situação. Vou tentar te ajudar. Veja se esse código serve pra você. Tenta se basear nele para elaborar o seu projeto e resolver seu problema.

```html
<div id="data">
  <section>
    <form action="enviar-dados.php" method="post">

      <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" required>

      <br>
      <label for="sobrenome">Sobrenome:</label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="sobrenome" name="sobrenome" required>
      <br>

      <label for="cargo">Cargo:</label>
      <br>
      <select id="cargo" name="cargo">
        <option value="desenvolvedorFront">Desenvolvedor - Front-End</option>
        <option value="desenvolvedorBack">Desenvolvedor - Back-End</option>
        <option value="designerGrafico">Designer Gráfico</option>
        <option value="auditor">Auditor</option>
        <option value="analistaFinanceiro">Analísta Financeiro</option>
      </select>

      <br>
      <button id="confirmar" type="submit">Confirmar</button>

    </form>

  </section>
</div>


<!-- ARQUIVO ENVIAR-DADOS.PHP -->

<?php
  
  $nome = $_POST["nome"];
  $sobrenome = $_POST["sobrenome"];
  $cargo = $_POST["cargo"];

  $insert = "INSERT INTO tbl_cadastro(nome, sobrenome, cargo) 
 VALUES('$nome','$sobrenome','$cargo')";
 
 $insert_execucao = mysqli_query($conexao, $insert);

?>
```

- No código criamos um um form (que vai enviar os dados que você quer cadastrar no banco de dados para o arquivo enviar-dados.php). É esse arquivo PHP que você realiza a query de inserção dos dados no banco de dados. Especificamos esse arquivo php no "action" do form.
- Adicionamos o "name" nos inputs, pq é pelo name que o arquivo PHP vai reconhecer os campos vindo do formulário.
- No arquivo PHP (enviar-dados.php), recebemos os dados vindo do formulário e passamos eles para variáveis. (Lembrando que estou me baseando que tenhamos criado um código PHP na mesma página que está o arquivo do seu código HTML)
- Depois (partindo do pressuposto que o nome da sua tabela no banco de dados fosse "tbl_cadastro" e tivesse os campos nome, sobrenome e cargo) realizamos um insert dos dados vindos do formulário nessa sua tabela).
- Por último executamos a query e concluímos a inserção com o mysqli_query.
- Esclarecendo que a variável "$conexao" deve guardar os seus dados de conexão com o banco de dados.
- Talvez (talvez não, precisa mesmo) precisasse ter um require_once, no início do arquivo php, chamando esse seu arquivo que realiza a conexão.
- O seu código postado não possui muitas informações. Talvez por essa minha resposta você possa ter um norte (não o norte de Game of Thrones, rs) para resolver sua situação.
- Valeu.

Comment: Certo, muito obrigado consegui resolver meu problema utilizando sua explicação.

Comment: Show de bola, @JoãoPedroAntoniazi , Continue neste caminho. Que a força esteja com você!

Comment: E contigo também!